# SSRS 2008 R2 service account - what are least privileges required for domain account?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm a developer writing up deployment documentation for our production administrators detailing how to install the SSRS 2008 R2 service on a machine other than the database server; the standard server deployment as shown at following link:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157293.aspx

We want to use a domain account to run the service but I've been asked to provide details of the minimum set of priveleges required by this domain account to run the service. I've had a hunt through MSDN\google\Stackoberflow and cannot find any specification\recommendation for this. It all seems pretty vague in MSDN but the production guys want exact details. I don't usually get into this level of detail around permissions! Can anyone point me to a resource for this? Or suggest another approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found the answer in technet

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx